# Cannot run mongod service

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run mongodb but I'm getting this error:
[image]

I tried to do this but not working:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --repair
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --journal
```

Running next command:
[image]

Restarted server and log.
[image]
Any idea? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Run this command `netstat -nltpd` to find out is that port up or no, also add more log from mongo server `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: edited with the command @MohammadEfazati

Comment: check your mongo server logs too and upload lines that happened after the restart

Comment: edited with restart log @MohammadEfazati

Comment: I think this error happening because your data dir is not correct. check the path and see is it correct? if not try to update it.
you can change it with `--dbpath`